# Is there any way to delete notifications?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I can't seem to find a way at all, and I'm wondering if I'm just missing something or if this is just plain not possible.

I know that you can turn off receiving notifications for individual games/apps, but I *do* want to keep receiving the notifications. I just want a way to delete the old ones when I've read them. Is there any way to do this or some other workaround to make them go away that doesn't involve turning off receiving them entirely from various games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible. You can, like you said, opt out of notifications for specific things, but you can't delete notifications you have already received.

Comment: Aw man. I can foresee my notification list getting rather unwieldy in the future. :(

Comment: Yeah, it is a pain. I tend to ignore the notifications completely, because usually the green or blue dot appears on the icon of whatever is affected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this used to be a feature originally! I remember trying to delete all the notifications caused by Nikki and then giving up because she had too many new swap note lessons to teach. Many months and a graduation later, I came back to the game to find this option removed.

So no, there is no way to delete notifications.

Comment: Hey tabbysam, welcome to the site.

Comment: Welcome! This is a Q&A site, not a blog :) Your answer did answer the question but it was kind of buried in all the ranting and introduction stuff. We prefer keeping it straight and to the point on the site, leaving social interaction to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge). Once you get 20 reputation, you're welcome to hang out. Enjoy E3!